# uninitialized constant Stripe::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, stripe-payments

I'm hitting an uninitialized constant, while working with Stripe, Rails (3.2.8) and Ruby (1.9.2).

Initially, my Sales model used the following (this works!):

```
def charge_card
  begin
    save!
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      amount: self.amount,
      currency: "usd",
      card: self.stripe_token,
      description: self.email,
    )
    self.finish!
  rescue Stripe::Error => e
    self.update_attributes(error: e.message)
    self.fail!
  end
end
```

Then, I decided I wanted to update that record with some additional information from Stripe, so I changed it to the following:

```
def charge_card
  begin
    save!
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      amount: self.amount,
      currency: "usd",
      card: self.stripe_token,
      description: self.email,
    )
    self.update(
      stripe_id:       charge.id,
      card_expiration: Date.new(charge.card.exp_year, Charge.card.exp_month, 1),
      fee_amount:      charge.fee
    )
    self.finish!
  rescue Stripe::Error => e
    self.update_attributes(error: e.message)
    self.fail!
  end
end
```

This results in the following: `uninitialized constant Stripe::Error`

I'd love to get some help/guidance on how I can properly update the record.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

First add stripe to your gemfile

```
gem 'stripe'
```

then do a `bundle install`

then create a file `config/initializers/stripe.rb` and put in the following code

```
require "stripe"
```

now restart your server.

Comment: The `require` should not be needed with Bundler.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: The gem is already installed – and initialized. The issue is with the self.update statement.

Comment: This did fix an error for me when I got the undefined constant Stripe error while trying to rescue Stripe::StripeError in a controller. For some reason, when I added require 'stripe' to the initializer (in which I have already been assigning an API key to the Stripe gem) the error went away. Not sure if it fixes the original problem though.

Answer (score 5):

The `Stripe` module doesn't implement an `Error` class, only a `StripeError` class. See the [stripe-ruby documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/stripe/stripe-ruby/Stripe)

If you change your code to

```
def charge_card
  begin
    ...
    charge = Stripe::Charge.create()
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    self.update_attributes(error: e.message)
    self.fail!
  end
end
```

It should work.